# how to convert string "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.mmm" to the datetime in c#

Tags: c#

I try to convert string type "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.mmm" to the datetime using the way below:

```
DateTime result;
string c;

tarihSaat[n - 4] = DateTime.ParseExact(c, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.mmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I got FormatException error. How can I convert it?
Thanks..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to get the string to look like (i.e. what's the pattern of the DateTime you're trying to get back?)

Comment: what is c ? What is held in that string? (you don't show it)

Comment: @JToland, it's not a matter of getting the string to look like anything. It's converting from a string to a DateTime object.

Comment: OH, sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to do :)

Comment: You should probably rename the question, since the title contains an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it, you can't reuse a format string pattern twice ("m" in your sample), also you want to use "fff" for milliseconds. For details on custom date and time format strings check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

```
string c = "15.04.2011 14:32:15.444";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(c, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: thank you:) just one more question : how we can control a string comes that format or not?

Comment: @derya: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'll try to answer - you can use TryParseExact instead of ParseExact, which returns a bool - if the result is true your date was successfully parsed, if not the string is not in the right format.